# I got this error on laravel project- Error Exception Trying to get property 'sales_price' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, helper

I get this error form helper.php. I need sale prices of product. but I get this error.And I dont understand when I get this error.

> helper.php

```
public static function getSalesPriceUsingProductIDCode($id, $customerId)
{
    $data = PosCustomerProducts::valid()->where('complete_status',0)->where('customer_id', $customerId)->where('product_id', $id)
    ->select('product_id', 'sales_price')
    ->first()->sales_price;
    return $data;
}
```

> orderSheetExport.php

```
if(isset($results[$product->id]))
{   
    if (Helper::getSalesPriceUsingProductIDCode($product->id,$results['customer_id'])==0)
    { 
        $excel_dynamic_data_values[$index][] =   $product->whole_sale_price * $results[$product->id];
        $productArray[$rsm_id][$product->id] += $results[$product->id] * $product->whole_sale_price;
        $singleProductArray[$rsm_id][$product->id] = $productArray[$rsm_id][$product->id];
        
    }else
    {    
        $excel_dynamic_data_values[$index][] = Helper::getSalesPriceUsingProductIDCode($product->id,$results['customer_id']) * $results[$product->id];       
        $productArray[$rsm_id][$product->id]       += $results[$product->id] *  Helper::getSalesPriceUsingProductIDCode( $product->id,$results['customer_id']);
        $singleProductArray[$rsm_id][$product->id] = $productArray[$rsm_id][$product->id];   
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Maybe `first()` does not return an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem. I also understand Why I was getting this error. When I use this helper function on a loop. It get some values that were not any sale price data. So it though this error.
So, I write if else condition on it.

Helper.php

```php
public static function getSalesPriceUsingProductIDCode($id, $customerId)
{
    $data = PosCustomerProducts::valid()->where('complete_status',0)->where('customer_id', $customerId)->where('product_id', $id)
    ->select('product_id', 'sales_price')
    ->first();
        if ($data) {
            $data = $data->sales_price;
        } else {
            $data = 0;
        }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the sales_price use `value` function

```
public static function getSalesPriceUsingProductIDCode($id, $customerId)
{
    $data = PosCustomerProducts::valid()->where('complete_status',0)->where('customer_id', $customerId)->where('product_id', $id)
    ->select('product_id', 'sales_price')
    ->value('sales_price');
    return $data;
}
```

Kindly refer value() in [Laravel Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)